# vagrant port forward not working, iptables not running

Tags: vagrant

I just create a Django web application on port 4500.Vagrant file config as below

`config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 4500, host: 4500`

But I can't access localhost:4500 on my browser. The iptables service is not running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do a quick `nmap` scan on the host, see if the port 4500 is open, or enable debugging output when starting the VM to see why port forwarding fails.

`VAGRANT_LOG=info vagrant up`

It is possible that you hit port collisions problem, try to enable auto correct. e.g.

```rb
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 4500, host: 4500,
    auto_correct: true
end
```

Pay attention to the output when you do `vagrant reload` or `vagrant up`.